How do I find the generating function for the set $$ L of strings over $\{ 0 , 1 , 2\} $ that do not contain "$12$" as a substring?
How do I find the generating function for the set $L$ of strings over $\{0, 1, 2\}$ that do not contain "$12$" as a substring?
I am working on finding the generating function for the set $L$ of strings composed of the characters $\{0, 1, 2\}$ which do not include the substring "$12$". Let $a_{l, m, n}$ denote the number of strings in $L$ where $l$ is the number of $0$'s, $m$ is the number of $1$'s, and $n$ is the number of $2$'s. I need to determine the generating function:
$$ G(x, y, z) = \sum_{l, m, n} a_{\ell, m, n} x^l y^m z^n.$$
Here is my approach:
Case $1$: For the strings starting with $0$, The rest of the string can be any valid string, so we have
$$G_0(x, y, z) = x G(x, y, z).$$
Case $2$: For the strings starting with $1$, then the next character can't be a $2$, so we have
$$G_1(x, y, z) = y(G_0(x, y, z) + G_1(x, y, z)).$$
Case $3$: For the strings starting with $2$, The rest of the string can be any valid string, so we have
$$G_2(x, y, z) = zG(x, y, z).$$
This is how I think it should be done, we end up combining all the cases. However I am stuck here so could anyone provide a detailed explanation or derivation of this generating function?

I think that (i) you've missed a "$y$" in the $G_1$ formula, should be $G_1=y(G_0+G_1)$ (ii) typo in case (3, should be "starting with $2$"

It's not clear from what you write whether you are counting the empty string as valid. I think that you must, so that the combination is $G=1+G_0+G_1+G_2$ and so $G=(1-x-(1-y)^{-1}xy-z)^{-1}$.

@ancientmathematician I am not following how you add the generating functions. Could you elaborate on that?

My previous comment was too hasty. I will post a solution.

For your analysis to work we have to count the empty string as a valid string.
Then with your notation we have as a result of your analysis (correcting the strings that start with "1": these are either 1, or 10 ..., or 11 ...):
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
G_0 &=&xG\\
G_1&=&y(1+G_0+G_1)\\
G_2&=&zG.
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Hence
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
G_0 &=&xG\\
(1-y)G_1&=&y(1+xG)\\
G_2&=&zG.
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Now every valid string is either empty, or begins with a 0 or a 1 or a 2. Hence
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
G&=&1+G_0+G_1+G_2\\
&=&1+xG+(1-y)^{-1}y(1+xG)+zG
\end{eqnarray}
$$
which gives
$$
G(1-x-z-(1-y)^{-1}yx)=(1-y)^{-1}y+1=(1-y)^{-1}
$$
or
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
G&=&(1-y)^{-1}(1-x-z-(1-y)^{-1}yx)^{-1}\\
&=&(1-x-y-z+yz)^{-1}
\end{eqnarray}
$$
if I have made no foolish slips.

Thank you. This is very clear!
